# FragmentStatePagerAdapter and ViewPager: Fragments instantiate out of order

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter with ViewPager to achieve a sequential slide scroll view (similar to most pdf readers). However, while running the code, the following is happening:

1. When the activity becomes visible, the first page is instantiated with a different (2nd) page's value. However, when scrolled to some other page and then back to page 1, the page displays default text from layout file.
2. Only 2nd and 2nd to last pages instantiate with the passed value (that too with values from other pages, not their own). Rest of the pages display default text from layout file.

On debugging, I noticed that the index/currentItemNumber changes when ViewPager.populate() calls ViewPager.addNewItem(). Ever more strange is the fact that setText() is called on the TextView (part of fragment layout), but text does not change from the default text.

Am I missing something?

Here is the code below:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private ViewPager mPager;
private Button mButtonFirst;
private Button mButtonPrev;
private Button mButtonGoTo;
private Button mButtonNext;
private Button mButtonLast;
private TextView mPageCount;
private EditText mPageNumber;
private TextView mError;
private int mNumScreens;
private int mCurrScreen;
private MyPagerAdapter mMyPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setUpViews();
    setUpListeners();
    setUpPager();
}

private void setUpViews() {
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.my_pager);

    // Get other view handles...

    mError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error_details);
}


private void setUpListeners() {
    // Set this class as click handler for all buttons
}

private void setUpPager() {

    String[] strings = new String[] {
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4",
            "5",
            "6"
        };

    // Success!
    // Set adapter and update views
    mMyPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), strings);
    mPager.setAdapter(mMyPagerAdapter);
    mNumScreens = strings.length;
    mPageCount.setText("/" + Integer.toString(mNumScreens));
    mCurrScreen = -1;
    GoToScreen(1);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    // Handle options

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_first:
            GoToScreen(1);
            break;
        case R.id.button_prev:
            GoToScreen(mCurrScreen - 1);
            break;
        case R.id.button_goto:
        {
            int screen;
            boolean reset = false;
            try {
                screen = Integer.parseInt(mPageNumber.getText().toString());
                reset = !SetToScreen(screen);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                reset = true;
            }
            if(reset) {
                mPageNumber.setText(Integer.toString(mCurrScreen));
            }
        }
        break;
        case R.id.button_next:
            GoToScreen(mCurrScreen + 1);
            break;
        case R.id.button_last:
            GoToScreen(mNumScreens);
            break;
    }
}

private void GoToScreen(int screen) {
    if(SetToScreen(screen)) {
        mPageNumber.setText(Integer.toString(mCurrScreen));
    }
}

private boolean SetToScreen(int screen) {

    // Switch to a valid screen
    if(screen >= 1 && screen <= mNumScreens && mCurrScreen != screen) {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(screen - 1, false);


        // Handle button visibility

        // Update current screen
        mCurrScreen = screen;

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

MyPagerAdapter.java

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private final String[] mStrings;

public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String[] strings) {
    super(fm);
    mStrings = strings;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mStrings.length;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return ScreenFragment.newInstance(mStrings[position]);
}
}
```

ScreenFragment.java

```
public class ScreenFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String ARG_SCREEN_STRING= "screen_string";

private String mScreenInfo;
private TextView mStatementLabel;


public static ScreenFragment newInstance(String screenString) {
    ScreenFragment fragment = new ScreenFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_SCREEN_STRING, screenString);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public ScreenFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mScreenInfo = getArguments().getString(ARG_SCREEN_STRING);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setUpViews();
    setUpFields();
}

private void setUpFields() {
    mStatementLabel.setText(mScreenInfo);
}

private void setUpViews() {
    mStatementLabel = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.qnr_screen_statement);
}

}
```

Comment: You are missing a minimal, complete, and verifiable example:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when I moved calls to setUpViews() and setUpFields() to onCreateView() from onActivityCreated(), with little modifications. This is how the new onCreateView() looks like (I moved the content of the above mentioned functions here)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen, container, false);
    mStatementLabel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.qnr_screen_statement);
    mStatementLabel.setText(mScreenInfo);
    return v;
}
```

I am yet to figure out why that was causing the problem. Will update if I find anything.

Comment: It is easier to do the GUI work in onCreateView() or safer onViewCreated(). When you the GUI code in onActivityCreated(), it is not getting the correct View which is depending on current Activity, getActivity(). The main thing is getting the correct View instead of Activity.